# QSystemTrayIcon: works in KDE and Windows, but not in Gnome Fallback/XFCE

Tags: qt, qt4, system-tray, trayicon

I have a small application that uses QSystemTrayIcon to show information in balloon. It works fine in Windows and in KDE, but doesn't in Gnome Fallback and XFCE. Here is how it looks in KDE when clicked:

[image]

And here is what's happening when clicking it in Gnome Fallback: it is clicked with left mouse button, but behaves like it was clicked with right button, i.e. shows "Exit", and when clicked by right button, shows "About":

[image]

Is there a way to make the icon work in every DE?

Here is the code:

```
MyTray::MyTray(QObject *parent) :
      QObject(parent)
{
//..........
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Выход",this));
    connect(menu.actions()[0],SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(delete_itself()));
    icn=QIcon(":new/prefix1/08-01.png");
    icon.setIcon(icn);
    icon.setContextMenu(&menu);
    connect(&icon,SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),this,SLOT(icon_clicked(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
    icon.show();
//..........
}
void MyTray::icon_clicked(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    if(reason==QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger)
    {
        QString s;
        for(int i=0;i<vec.count();i++)
        {
            s.append(vec[i].room);
            s.append(vec[i].isOpen ? ": открыт" : ": закрыт");
            if(vec.count()-1>i) s.append("\n");
        }
        QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon ic = QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon(QSystemTrayIcon::Information);
        icon.showMessage("Состояние",s,ic,20000);
    }
}
```

Comment: It _might_ be a bug. What version of Qt are you using? If using Qt 4, try updating to 4.8.7. It would be even better if you could move to Qt 5 and even, if possible, to the latest release of  5.6 or 5.9, as both of them are LTS release and are the only currently supported versions of Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself. In GNOME and its derivatives, the only supported action for tray icon is context menu, unlike KDE where the icon can be also activated by the left click. There is a package [sni-qt](https://github.com/bkanuka/sni-qt), that can add a point "Activate" to the context menu. I've installed this package and added to `~/.config/sni-qt.conf`:

```
[need-activate-action]
itray
```

where `itray` is my app. So now it's possible to do what I wanted in two mouse clicks instead of one.